# What files do I edit to be able to maximize Finder windows to fill the screen by shift-clicking the green button?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

Is there a group of files or a single file I can edit to facilitate maximizing "Finder" windows to fill the entire screen just as other application windows by shift-clicking the green plus button?

Comment: I don't know about any specific file to edit but I can highly recommend [Better Snap Tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) ($1.99). It's by far my preferred solution for application window manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an application like [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate), [Amethyst](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst), [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt), or [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) instead.

If you use Slate, for example adding

```
bind m:alt move screenOriginX;screenOriginY screenSizeX;screenSizeY
```

to `~/.slate` makes option-m maximize a window.